# can not find the driver in /proc/device

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I want to compile a device driver in kernel, and I configure it with *, (not in module ). After the compilation, I can't see the device in `/proc/device`. Also I check the output of `make bzImage`, the driver has been compiled. Do I need to delete the two lines:

```
module_init(mydriver_init);

module_exit(mydriver_exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to understand your problem. You should show some code.

Anyway, */proc/devices* does not show all kernel module. It shows devices, maybe your driver is not registering a device.

You can put some `printk()` in your code and read it with the command `dmesg` from your terminal. If your read your print, your module is loaded.

Evan if you do not compile a module as module, but you built it within the kernel, functions

```
module_init(mydriver_init);
module_exit(mydriver_exit);
```

must be there. `mydriver_init` will be executed when the kernel load your driver, `module_exit` will be executed when the kernel unload your driver.

Answer (score 0):

The `/proc/devices` file which is read-only doesn't seem to be editable or viewable using editors like VIM. So try `'cat /proc/devices'`, your device may show up then.